# Poblema al mostrar una coleccion mediante un foreach

Tags: c#, array, foreach, colecciones

Estoy empezando a programar y quisiera que me respondieran esta duda.
Estoy usando un foreach para recibir los datos de una colección en c#, pero al usar otro foreach para mostrar la información al usuario solo me escribe System.int32[] o me muestra todo vacío.
Si encuentran otro error me lo pueden decir, mi intención es aprender como funciona c#.

```
Console.WriteLine("Digite la cantidad de estudiantes a registrar");
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] nombre = new string[n];
        int[] calificacion = new int[1];
        Console.WriteLine("Ingresa los datos siguientes");
        foreach (string nombres in nombre)
        {
            Console.Write("Nombre: ");
            Console.ReadLine();
            foreach (int calificaciones in calificacion)
            {
                Console.Write("Calificacion: ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        foreach (string show in nombre)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Nombre: {show}");
            Console.WriteLine("Calificacion: " + calificacion);
            Console.WriteLine("**************************************************");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Los datos ingresados son: ");
        Console.WriteLine($"Nombre: {nombre} \nCalficacion: {calificacion}");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tus errores son los siguientes:

1. No estas almacenando los datos en los arrays, solo los estas leyendo de consola mas no lo almacenas
2. Estas imprimiendo el arreglo, mas no los datos, recuerda que los
   arreglos son objetos por ello al escribir `Console.WriteLine(array)`
   te sale System.int32[]

Como corregirlo?

1. para almacenar en el arreglo lo que debes de hacer es quitar el
   foreach ya que esto solo te trae el valor mas no te deja modificar
   el valor almacenado en el arreglo

   ```
   for (int index = 0; index < nombre.lenght;index++)
   {
       Console.Write("Nombre: ");
       //almacenamos el nombre en el arreglo
       nombre[i] = Console.ReadLine();
       for (int indexCalificacion = 0; indexCalificacion < calificacion.lengt; indexCalificacion ++)
       {
           Console.Write("Calificacion: ");
           //Igual almacenamos la calificacion en el arreglo(parseamos el string que lee para poder almacenarlo en una variable tipo int)
           calificacion[indexCalificacion] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       }
   }
   ```
2. Para imprimir los valores almacenados en un array, tenemos que
   reccorrer el array

   ```
   foreach (string show in nombre)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"Nombre: {show}");
       foreach(int cal in calificacion)
       Console.WriteLine("Calificacion: " + cal);
          Console.WriteLine("**************************************************");

   }
   ```